# Amyuni PDF Creator for .net validations javascript

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation, syncfusion

Does Amyuni PDF Creator support creation of validations in the PDF using Javascripts, printing of pdf documents etc. ? If so, how ? I have been experimenting with the trial of this control and have not been able to find any reference to validations, actions or javascript anywhere?
Or 
Any other product which offers similar functionalities ?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a validation and printing in PDF document with JavaScripts using Syncfusion essential PDF. We have created the sample to achieve this. Please find the sample available in the link  below,

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/141635/ze/Pdfjava_script_actions-63987573

You can refer the sample for printing the PDF document using JavaScripts in the following link,
http://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5080/how-to-print-the-existing-pdf-document-using-pdfjavascript

Please let us know if you have any concerns.